# I am generating a tagged PDF with itext 7. When adding a TOC with links, the document fails the tagged annotation check in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, itext, accessibility, acrobat, itext7

I am using the code below to create a paragraph with a goto action to go elsewhere in my PDF document. I run this code at the end of the PDF generation and then move the TOC page to its proper place in the document. When I run the document through Adobe Acrobat's accessibility check, it fails and says that for each link on the TOC page there is an untagged annotation. This is the only place the document fails tagging.

Here is the basic code:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().add("textToBeLinked").setAction(PdfAction.createGoTo("aNamedDestination"));
```

EDIT - Here is the code including tabs:

```
TabStop tabStop = new TabStop(widthFormatting, TabAlignment.RIGHT, new DottedLine(1.5f, 2.5f));
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().addTabStops(tabStop).addStyle(style);
paragraph.add("first part of text to link");
paragraph.add(new Tab());
paragraph.add("second part of text to link");
paragraph.setAction(PdfAction.createGoTo("namedDestination");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your link to be properly tagged, use `Link` layout element in the following way:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().add(new Link("textToBeLinked", PdfAction.createGoTo("aNamedDestination")));
```

You may notice that a black border would appear. If you want to get rid of it, you can create `PdfLinkAnnotation` explicitly and set its rectangle to some random values. iText layout would rewrite them to the correct position for you:

```
PdfLinkAnnotation annotation = new PdfLinkAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));
annotation.setAction(PdfAction.createGoTo("aNamedDestination"));
annotation.setBorder(new PdfArray(new float[]{0, 0, 0}));

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().add(new Link("textToBeLinked", annotation));
```

If you want the link to be clickable along the whole width of the page, you can modify the initial approach you took with adding action to the paragraph by setting its role correctly, but you should check the nesting of the elements yourself so that it is appropriate:

```
paragraph.getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(StandardRoles.LINK);
```

Comment: The main issue with using a Link for me is that I want to have the text that is clickable for the link separated by a tab with a dotted line. (title......pageNumber for example) I have edited the code in the question to represent this. I cannot see a way to include a tab in the Link constructor as it seems to only take in Strings for the first argument.

Comment: Also, I am unsure if we are using different versions of iText or not, but StandardRoles is not defined for me (PdfNames seems to be what I should use) and .getAccessibilityProperties().setRole() is not a method, but paragraph.setRole() is. If I use

paragraph.setRole(PdfName.Link);

however, I get the following error:

PdfException: Inline level or illustration element cannot contain kids.

Comment: @scott13, You must be using iText 7.0.x. I am using iText 7.1.x

Comment: Tagging is something that has been heavily improved in iText 7.1, so I strongly recommend that you switch to 7.1 version which is the most up to date and actively developed version of iText.

Comment: Upgrading to iText 7.1 fixed the problem, but I do have one problem that stemmed from that. I need to move the table of contents from the last page to the third. I used to do this by removing it, setting a PdfPage equal to what removePage returned, and then adding the page where I wanted it. However, it seems iText 7.1 changed this and removePage returns void now. I cannot just use movePage as it says it cannot move a page in partially flushed document. Any advice?

Comment: I recommend closing the document after creating the TOC and then using a  `PdfDocument(PdfReader, PdfWriter)` to move the page. So you would have two instances of the `PdfDocument`, one used after another. If you want to to it with one instance only, create `Document` with `immediateFlush=false`, call `document.flush();` after you've added all the content, and then move pages with `pdfDocument.movePage()`.